# i want to use RSSReader in CodenameOne

Tags: java, codenameone

i want to use RSSReader in CodenameOne ,i found the API class i put it in a new class that i create but i don't know how to call it in MyApplication Class and execute it.
this is the link of the RSS API Class:

https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?code=codenameone/CodenameOne/CodenameOne-master/CodenameOne/src/com/codename1/components/RSSReader.java

please help me

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and post a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

you should:

1- instanciate your RSS class into your MyApplication.java class

2- Create a container wich receive the result of the invokation of the createDemo() method (also in the MyApplication.java)

3- Add this container to a new Form, then show the form.

Comment: I would also add that you can use `RSSService` and build the UI from that.